# Select query php

Tags: php, select

I have a query which selects from the 'users' table and filters the  'vehicle_make' and 'dealer_group' tables.
The values for the dealer_group are either 'North', 'East', 'South' and 'West'. If a logged in user has the values 'East' they will only see users with the same 'vehicle_make' and 'dealer_group'.

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM users 
          WHERE vehicle_make = '".$_SESSION['vehicle_make']."'
            AND dealer_group = '".$_SESSION['dealer_group']."'
          ORDER BY ".$order_by." LIMIT ".$start.", ".$display;
```

What I am trying to do is come up with a query for someone who can see all of the users with the North, East, West, South values but still filter out the other users who have the single value. I would prefer not to put all of these values within the table on the database (ie a value of 'North, West, South, East') but is there a quick and simple way of doing this?

Comment: There are only 2 solutions to this from what I gather. First, select all users and allow filtering on front-end. Second, based on the front-end filter apply SQL statement filter and return the result. Is there a live example of this kind of functionality you're trying to replicate?

Comment: Please add here sample table data, and the resulting data you want to achieve.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific or there is not way we can do anything other than make guesses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For users who can see all dealer groups, leave the session variable blank. Then do:

```
$dealer_group = empty($_SESSION['dealer_group']) ? " " : "AND dealer_group = '{$_SESSION['dealer_group']}'";
$query = "SELECT  * FROM users 
          WHERE vehicle_make = '{$_SESSION['vehicle_make']}'
            $dealer_group
          ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start, $display";
```

This way, if they aren't restricted to a specific dealer group, it just leaves out that part of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You are a life saver !  Thank you, this works perfectly!